# where can I find the complete details of a predefined attributes or parameters

Tags: grails

If I want to find the complete details of the attributes of any tag in grails, where can I find it, like the following code

```
<g:render template="/common/formField"
model="[name:'owner', bean:ownerBean, field:'firstName', label:'First Name']" />
```

In the above tag its having template and model, template is used to render predefined or user defined form, and model is used to tell which model to apply the template. but in the above code model contains name,bean, field,label parameters, are they predefined If so where does I get all those details I did not find in the API as well as  in grails documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to discover all the attributes supported by a Grails tag, see the the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/). The tag docs are in the "Quick Reference" sidebar under the "Tags" heading. The attributes of `model` are not predefined, i.e. you can put any key-value pairs in the model.

Comment: are they model's map key value pairs are predefined or user defined (like in the above sample code which contains name,bean etc).

Comment: I saw that doc but its not having the model's key value pair list, My question is are those like in above code name,bean are predefined are used defined

Comment: @srujan they are user-defined

Comment: I believe that the `model` will be handed off as a generic Map to the template, similar to the `params` field in a controller. It's up to the recipient of the map to make use of the fields in it.